# Visual Basic - False Position Root Finding

Tags: vba, loops

I'm trying to create a code that uses the false position method to find the roots of an equation. The equation is as follows:

y = x^(1.5sin⁡(x)) * e^(-x/7) + e^(x/10) - 4

I used a calculator to find the roots, and they are 6.9025, 8.8719, and 12.8079.

My VBA code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Function Func(x)
Func = (x ^ (1.5 * Sin(x))) * Exp(-x / 7) + Exp(x / 10) - 4
End Function
```

---

```
Function FalsePos(Guess1, Guess2)
Dim a, b, c As Single
Dim i As Integer

a = Guess1
b = Guess2

For i = 0 To 1000

c = a - Func(a) * (b - a) / (Func(b) - Func(a))

If (Func(c) < 0.00001) Then
    i = 1001
Else
    If Func(a) * Func(c) < 0 Then
        b = c
    Else
        a = c
    End If
End If
Next

FalsePos = c

End Function
```

My problem is that when I call the function and use for example 4 and 8 as my two guesses, the number it returns is 5.29 instead of the root between 4 and 8 which is 6.9025.

Is there something wrong with my code or am I just not understanding the false position method correctly?

Comment: Go through the code line by line and determine the results as they calculate - you should understand the math before you attempt to code it. When you get to a line where the calculation deviates from your mathematical expectation, you know where the error lies. If you haven't proven out your math, this isn't really a programming question.

Comment: Just figured it out. The first If statement needs to check for the absolute value of Func(c). Do I delete this post or is there something I need to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Double` for precision with Maths problems. Three other notes about coding that you may not be aware of:

```
dim a, b, c as Single
```

will `dim` `a` and `b` as `Variant`s, and `c` as a Single, and you can use `Exit For` to escape from a for loop, rather than setting the control variable out of the bounds. Finally, you should define the outputs of a `Function` by specifying `As ...` after the closing parenthesis.

You should use breakpoints (press F9 with the carrot in a line of code to breakpoint that line), then step through the code by pressing F8 to advance line-by-line to see what is happening, and keep your eye on the Locals window (Go to `View` > `Locals`)

This is the code with the above changes:

```
Function Func(x As Double) As Double
    Func = (x ^ (1.5 * Sin(x))) * Exp(-x / 7) + Exp(x / 10) - 4
End Function
```

---

```
Function FalsePos(Guess1 As Double, Guess2 As Double) As Double
    Dim a As Double, b As Double, c As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    a = Guess1
    b = Guess2
    For i = 0 To 1000
        c = a - Func(a) * (b - a) / (Func(b) - Func(a))
        If (Func(c) < 0.00001) Then
            Exit For
        Else
            If Func(a) * Func(c) < 0 Then
                b = c
            Else
                a = c
            End If
        End If
    Next
    FalsePos = c
End Function
```

Comment: These are good comments in addition to the OP's discussion of math above.